# Table analog of MakeQueryLayer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, table, query-layer

As of 10.1, `arcpy` provides the rather handy [`MakeQueryLayer`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000174000000) function. This allows us to use `arcpy` to create query layers programmatically instead of having to go through MXDs (as was the case in 10.0). This is extremely useful when working with a database that does not contain the SDE structure (formerly created via post-install and now created by Enable Enterprise Geodatabase, I believe) or where the tables you want to interact with have not been registered with SDE.

However, now I want to create a *table* instead of a feature layer/class, as in the query will not contain a shape column. How can I go about this?

### What I've tried:

I considered [`MakeQueryTable`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006r000000), but this takes an existing layer or table as an input, rather than a query.

I also just tried to use `MakeQueryLayer` and got some... confusing results. `conn` below is a `str` that contains the file path of my database connection file.

```
>>> r = arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(conn, 'TEST', 'SELECT ID AS OBJECTID, MY_TABLE.* FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE', oid_fields=['OBJECTID'])
>>> r.status
4
>>> r.outputCount
1
>>> r[0]
u'TEST'
>>> type(r[0])
<type 'unicode'>
```

The status code `4` [corresponds to Succeeded](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000046000000), but the result object contains a Unicode string as its only output. So I'm not sure if it successfully created a layer or table and I just can't find it or what. Normally, `MakeQueryLayer` outputs an actual `Layer` object:

```
>>> r2 = arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(conn, 'TEST2', 'SELECT ID AS OBJECTID, MY_TABLE_WITH_SHAPE.* FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_WITH_SHAPE', oid_fields=['OBJECTID'])
>>> r2.outputCount
1
>>> r2[0]
<map layer u'TEST2'>
>>> type(r2[0])
<class 'arcpy._mapping.Layer'>
```

I tried to do some work with `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers` and `arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews` to see if I could find the output layer, but those require an input document (and I'm not using a document).

My back end database happens to be Oracle, but I imagine that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got it working!

Note that "*[If the SQL query does not return a spatial column, the output will be a stand-alone table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000174000000)*"

```
>>> r = arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(conn, 'TEST', 'SELECT ID AS OBJECTID, MY_TABLE.* FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE', oid_fields=['OBJECTID'])
>>> r.status
4
>>> r.outputCount
1
>>> r[0]
u'TEST'
>>> type(r[0])
<type 'unicode'>
>>> with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r[0],['OBJECTID']) as rows:
>>>     for row in rows:
>>>         print row[0]
0
1
2
3
4
5
etc...
```

It's a bit confusing that the "layer" is a string instead of a Layer object, but I assume it's just a pointer (think layer/table name in ArcMap table of contents) to the underlying object.

Update: as per @jpmc26's comment, `t = arcpy.mapping.TableView(r[0])` will convert the result string into a TableView object.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot now. You can also get an actual object like this: `t = arcpy.mapping.TableView(r[0])`.

Comment: Thanks, I just learned something new ;). Answer updated.